# How can I resolve " InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: jpeg::Uncompress failed. Invalid JPEG data or crop window"?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Beginner here.

I recently converted my images to grayscale using opencv.
Then I used those images for training.
When I was training, there was an error.
"InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

```
jpeg::Uncompress failed. Invalid JPEG data or crop window.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_test_function_1748]"
```

Can someone please explain to me what it means?

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

image_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "IMAGES_G/",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    color_mode="grayscale",
    seed=123,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "IMAGES_G",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    color_mode="grayscale",
    seed=123,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)

class_names = ["med1", "med2", "med3","med4","med5","med6","med7","med8","med9","med10"]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

normalization_layer = layers.Rescaling(1./255)

import numpy as np

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))


model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 1))),
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))),
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')),
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')),
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2)),

model.add(layers.Flatten()),
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='softmax')),
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2)),
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data = val_ds,
    epochs = 50
)
```

And if you have any idea how to improve this code, I really appreciate it if you comment it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem in some of your training data. You can use the code below to check which image is corrupted and delete it.

```
from struct import unpack
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
    
marker_mapping = {
    0xffd8: "Start of Image",
    0xffe0: "Application Default Header",
    0xffdb: "Quantization Table",
    0xffc0: "Start of Frame",
    0xffc4: "Define Huffman Table",
    0xffda: "Start of Scan",
    0xffd9: "End of Image"
}
    
class JPEG:
    def __init__(self, image_file):
        with open(image_file, 'rb') as f:
            self.img_data = f.read()
    
    def decode(self):
        data = self.img_data
        while(True):
            marker, = unpack(">H", data[0:2])
            # print(marker_mapping.get(marker))
            if marker == 0xffd8:
                data = data[2:]
            elif marker == 0xffd9:
                return
            elif marker == 0xffda:
                data = data[-2:]
            else:
                lenchunk, = unpack(">H", data[2:4])
                data = data[2+lenchunk:]            
            if len(data)==0:
                break        
    
bads = []

for img in tqdm(images):
  image = osp.join(root_img,img)
  image = JPEG(image) 
  try:
    image.decode()   
  except:
    bads.append(img)


for name in bads:
  os.remove(osp.join(root_img,name))
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!